# normally distributed Sample data generation

Tags: python, dataframe, random, normal-distribution, data-generation

I have 10 sample data (array of int) and now I want to make it 100 and mean while I don’t want to just copy it 10 times.
Data = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

So I want to create 90 more data and if I copy it 9 times than each frequency will be 10 or evenly distributed. Which I don’t want but some other way where frequency randomly or at least not evenly  distributed.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with a sample of your input data and your expected output, as well as code for what you've tried based on your own research

Comment: Thanks edited it and make more clear.

Comment: See [Select one element from a list using python following the normal distribution
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472461/select-one-element-from-a-list-using-python-following-the-normal-distribution)

Comment: The requester wants 100 samples from a uniform distribution from 0-9 inclusive in an array as integers based on the description - I believe the use or "normal" in the title was an error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (which I am not sure I do) then you should look at using the numpy module which has easy built in ways of generating data with a normal distribution using [numpy.random.normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

You can look at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) and tweak it by adding the mean SD and number of values you need - 90 arranged into groups of 10?

```
import numpy as np

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, [10,9]) # [10,9] is the shape of data.
```

This leaves you with a numpy array (s) of the data, which is easy to access in the list format that you seem to be after.